# How can I use column relative position in if statement in order by?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I run a SQL query like below in MySQL:

```
select * 
from (
    select 2 as o,1 as t from dual 
    union 
    select 1 as o,2 as t from dual 
    ) x
order by if((select 1),o,t);
```

It works well, but when I use column relative position in `if` statement, it doesn't work.

How can I use column relative position in `if` in `ORDER BY` statement?

```
select * 
from (
    select 2 as o,1 as t from dual 
    union 
    select 1 as o,2 as t from dual 
    ) x
order by if((select 0),1,2);
```

Comment: Putting **`SQL`** in the **`HTML`** snippet won't run it. I'll correct it for you.

Comment: Can you please add input and expected output to help understand the question better?

Comment: Do you want to use column `t` for sorting when the record originates from the first query of the union and `o` when it comes from the second ?

Comment: Thank you to correct my answer.   @AngelPolitis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your real confusion is.  When an integer appears in an `order by`, then this is treated as a column number.  Any other use of an integer is interpreted as an expression.

The use of column numbers has been removed from the SQL standard.  Hence, its use in any particular database is not guaranteed in future releases.  It is really better to use the column names.

Comment: thank you ， I confuse that "order by if(1,1,0)" shoud be equal as  "order by 1"  owing to "if(1,1,0)"  = "1".

Comment: You mean , "order by if(1,1,0)" = "order by <number>"      and   "order by 1"   = "order by <columns index>"   is it?  @Linoff

Comment: @LanlanWang . . . Yes, that is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sort your query based on a criteria over two columns, if I'm correct, you can use something like this:

```
...
order by 
    case when (your criteria)
        then column1
        else column2
    end;
```

Note: use `union all` instead `union` when you don't want to remove duplicate values as performance issue ;).